# Reverse Locale Mapping in Java

Tags: java, localization, multilingual

I'm building a system where the `en-US` command `c!timezone set Okinawa` would be equivalent to the `ja-JP` command `c!タイムゾーン 設定 沖縄`, and the `pt-BR` command `c!fusohorário definir Okinawa`.

After I split on spaces, I need to look up what each token is, based on the user's locale. What's the best way to accomplish this? How can I make it so that changes for additional languages/locales can be easily made?

Comment: So the `ResourceBundle`'s `getString` would return `timezone` for each of the keys in `en-US`, `ja-JP`, and `pt-BR`?

Answer (score -1):

Apache commons:
LocaleUtils.toLocale(localeAsString)

Comment: I already have the user's Locale. Java Stdlib supports this. What I'm looking for is a way to map the internationalized words back to my supported keywords while I already have the user's locale.